# How to use CreateGridMesh in RuntimeMeshComponent

Tags: c++, unreal-4, unreal

I don't know to pass on the 5th parameter. I'm still new with C++ so if someone could help me with the pointer

```
void AGrid::GenerateMeshes_Implementation()
{
    FRuntimeMeshDataPtr Data = GetRuntimeMeshComponent()->GetOrCreateRuntimeMesh()->GetRuntimeMeshData();
    Data->EnterSerializedMode();

    Data->CreateMeshSection(0, false, false, 1, false, true, EUpdateFrequency::Average);

    auto Section = Data->BeginSectionUpdate(0);

    FVector BoxSize = FVector(100, 100, 100);
    URuntimeMeshShapeGenerator::CreateBoxMesh(BoxSize, *Section.Get());
    URuntimeMeshShapeGenerator::CreateGridMesh(128.0f, 128.0f, 64, 64, *Section.Get()); // <---- This one

    Section->Commit();
}
```

It says it needs to be a `TSharedPtr<FRuntimeMeshAccessor>&`

```
void URuntimeMeshShapeGenerator::CreateGridMesh(float Width, float Height, int32 NumSubdivisionsX, int32 NumSubdivisionsY, const TSharedPtr<FRuntimeMeshAccessor>& MeshBuilder)
{
    MeshBuilder->EmptyVertices(CREATEGRIDMESHTRIANGLES_NUMVERTS(NumSubdivisionsX, NumSubdivisionsY));
    MeshBuilder->EmptyIndices(CREATEGRIDMESHTRIANGLES_NUMTRIS(NumSubdivisionsX, NumSubdivisionsY));
    FVerticesBuilderFunction VerticesBuilder = [&](const FVector& Position, const FVector& Normal, const FRuntimeMeshTangent& Tangent, const FVector2D& UV0)
    {
        int32 NewVertex = MeshBuilder->AddVertex(Position);
        MeshBuilder->SetNormalTangent(NewVertex, Normal, Tangent);
        MeshBuilder->SetUV(NewVertex, UV0);
    };

    FTrianglesBuilderFunction TrianglesBuilder = [&](int32 Index)
    {
        MeshBuilder->AddIndex(Index);
    };

    CreateGridMesh(Width, Height, NumSubdivisionsX, NumSubdivisionsY, VerticesBuilder, TrianglesBuilder);
}
```

Comment: Just a couple comments to help you get this answered:

1. It looks like you are using 3rd party (not built in) components, such as URuntimeMeshShapeGenerator. Ideally you can provide a documentation link for each of these.
2. You didn't provide the compilation error. That would help identify the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Change this:**

```c
URuntimeMeshShapeGenerator::CreateGridMesh(128.0f, 128.0f, 64, 64, *Section.Get());
```

**to this:**

```c
URuntimeMeshShapeGenerator::CreateGridMesh(128.0f, 128.0f, 64, 64, Section->GetReadonlyMeshAccessor());
```

#### More Info

It looks like you are using [Koderz/RuntimeMeshComponent](https://github.com/Koderz/RuntimeMeshComponent/).

The 5th parameter of `URuntimeMeshShapeGenerator::CreateGridMesh` is a `const TSharedPtr<FRuntimeMeshAccessor>&`.

The type returned from `FRuntimeMeshData::BeginSectionUpdate` is a `TUniquePtr<FRuntimeMeshScopedUpdater>`. Your `Section` variable also has this type.

When you call `*Section.Get()` for the 5th parameter, you are attempting to pass in a `FRuntimeMeshScopedUpdater`, which does match and results in the compilation error.

You need to get the `FRuntimeMeshAccessor` with `FRuntimeMeshData::GetReadonlyMeshAccessor`.

The `Get()` method you were calling was a Get() on TUniquePtr, part of the [Unreal Smart Pointer Library](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Programming/UnrealArchitecture/SmartPointerLibrary/index.html). It did not get the `FRuntimeMeshAccessor` you needed.